# asp.net core with react load image from web root

Tags: asp.net, image, reactjs, asp.net-core, local

I have an asp.net core web project which uses React and another project which serves as the API. The API saves images to a folder called Images in the content root directory, now I need to retrieve those images and show them in an  attribute. But, since they are locally stored there, I can't just put the absolute local url in there, nor can I use cshtml methods to resolve it, how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding app.UseStaticFiles() to your Program.cs